# Async Functions: Future<Query Snapshot> to Bool in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, async-await, future

I have this piece of code right here: if the user exists in the database and it's followed by the CurrentUser it builds an "Unfollow" custom button, otherwise it builds a follow button

```
CustomButton follow = CustomButton("Follow", Colors.red, Colors.red, Colors.white, user);
CustomButton unfollow = CustomButton("Unfollow", Colors.black, Colors.black, Colors.white, user);

AvatarHeader(user.username, " ", user.photoURL, checkIfFollowing(user.id)== true ? unfollow : follow)
```

the checkIfFollowing() function is always evaluated false probably because I have a problem in this asyncronus function which does not return a boolean value

```
  checkIfFollowing(String fetchedUser) async{
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await FOLLOWERS
        .document(fetchedUser)
        .collection('userFollowers')
        .document(CURRENTUSER.id)
        .get()

      return doc.exists;
  }
```

How can i fix this?

**EDIT**

```
  search(String query) {
    Future<QuerySnapshot> users = USERS
        .where("username", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query)
        .getDocuments();

        print(query);
        print("");
        onStringChange(users);

  }


FutureBuilder buildResults(){
    return FutureBuilder (
            future: results,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                print("i dont have data");
                return circularProgress();
              }
              List<AvatarHeader> searchResults = [];
              snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) async {
                User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
                if (user.photoURL != null) {
                  print(user.username);
                  bool check = await checkIfFollowing(user.id);                  
                  CustomButton follow = CustomButton("Follow", Colors.red, Colors.red, Colors.white, user);
                  CustomButton unfollow = CustomButton("Unfollow", Colors.black, Colors.black, Colors.white, user);
                  searchResults.add(AvatarHeader(user.username, " ", user.photoURL, check == true ? unfollow : follow));
                }
              });
              return ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                children: searchResults,
              );
            },
          );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a [Future](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future-class.html) in async functions, in your particular case you need a `Future<bool>`

```
Future<bool> checkIfFollowing(String fetchedUser) async{
  DocumentSnapshot doc = await FOLLOWERS
    .document(fetchedUser)
    .collection('userFollowers')
    .document(CURRENTUSER.id)
    .get()

   return doc.exists;
}
```

I recommend you to take a look to [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

> A future (lower case “f”) is an instance of the Future (capitalized “F”) class. A future represents the result of an asynchronous operation, and can have two states: uncompleted or completed.

**EDIT**

Without more details is very hard to be sure how to solve your specific issue. If I understand correctly, you need to have something in line with this

```
FutureBuilder buildResults() {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: results,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        print("i dont have data");
        return circularProgress();
      }

      // get documents where user.photoURL != null
      var docsWhereUserPhotoIsNotNull = getDocumentsWithUserPhotoNotNull(snapshot.data.documents);

      // build a list of FutureBuilders
      return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), 
          itemCount: docsWhereUserPhotoIsNotNull.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var doc = docsWhereUserPhotoIsNotNull[index];
            var user = User.fromDocument(doc);

            return FutureBuilder(
                future: checkIfFollowing(user.id),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return circularProgress();
                  }

                  bool check = snapshot.data;
                  CustomButton follow = CustomButton("Follow", Colors.red, Colors.red, Colors.white, user);
                  CustomButton unfollow = CustomButton(
                      "Unfollow", Colors.black, Colors.black, Colors.white, user);
                  return AvatarHeader(user.username, " ", user.photoURL, check == true ? unfollow : follow);
                });
          });
    }
  );
}
```

Where

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> getDocumentsWithUserPhotoNotNull(List<DocumentSnapshot> documents) {
   var documentsWithUserPhotoNotNull = List<DocumentSnapshot>();

   documents.forEach((doc) async {
     User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
     if (user.photoURL != null) {
       documentsWithUserPhotoNotNull.add(doc);
     }
   });

   return documentsWithUserPhotoNotNull;
 }
```

Comment: this seems to work but the problem now is that it fetches the results but the user interface isn't built anymore

Comment: Can you paste the complete widget in the question? (unless it's toob big) You need a `FutureBuilder` likely

Comment: It's too big unfortunately. I tried with a future builder, a nested future builder to be precise since it's a nested widget, and it loads the data but the avatars are not shown anymore

Comment: I pasted an example of a very simple example of a `FutureBuilder`... without seeing your real code will be hard to know if this nails the problem or not.

Comment: I edited the post, you almost got the point but as you can see i have already a futurebuilder inside, i tried to nest but the result i got is the same

Comment: You will need to move `await checkIfFollowing(user.id);` inside `results` future, can't you iterate the docs in the method generating the docs? Can you show the method that generates `results`?

Comment: it will be too difficult because i will couple too many objects and my code will look like spaghetti

Comment: @karalis1: later or tomorrow will try to write something. I think to have an idea of what you need.... I understand that you need another FutureBuilder to build **each element of the list**

Comment: thank you a lot man, i really appreciate it and already appreciated what you have done so far!

Comment: I'm sure that it doesn't compiles but the idea is to create a `ListView` of `FutureBuilder`... I'm sure it has errors but hopefully you capture the idea and helps you to continue from here.

Comment: i think we are almost here, it says now "type 'QuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'List<DocumentSnapshot>'" how can i cast that?

Comment: Help me a little :) I'm not familiar with `QuerySnapshot` where do you get that?

Comment: Maybe you need to change `getDocumentsWithUserPhotoNotNull(List<DocumentSnapshot> documents)` by `getDocumentsWithUserPhotoNotNull(QuerySnapshot documents)`

Comment: actullay the search function for the user which is not part of that class (added in the edit above) is the only part where QuerySnapshot is mentioned

Comment: ok i changed but now it says i can't use the for each to loop inside getDocumentsWithUserPhotoNotNull

Comment: I think I had this wrong `var docsWhereUserPhotoIsNotNull = getDocumentsWithUserPhotoNotNull(snapshot.data);`, that needs to be `var docsWhereUserPhotoIsNotNull = getDocumentsWithUserPhotoNotNull(snapshot.data.documents);` Maybe you can use again `List<DocumentSnapshot>`...

Comment: alright man now it's working but the problem is that inside this statement "bool check = snapshot.hasData;"  it's wrong because the snapshot always gets the data at some point from firebase, the value of that check needs to verify if the user exists in the currentuser's usersfollowing folder. So since that statement only check if the data gets retrived it always return true

Comment: Solved instead of snapshot.hasData it's better to use snapshot.data! Thanks a lot man! I'm editing your answer so i can add just 3 lines of code to render better the ui that can help everyone else!!

Comment: Glad it worked :) Did I write`bool check = snapshot.hasData;`? That's definitively wrong! I 100% mean to use `bool check = snapshot.data`